# Removing stopwords from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have the below script & in the last line, I am trying to remove stopwords from my string in the column called 'response'.

The problem is, instead of 'A bit annoyed' becoming 'bit annoyed' it actually drops even the letters - so, A bit annoyed would become bit nnoyed. Because 'a' is a stopword

Can anyone advise me?

```
   import pandas as pd
   from textblob import TextBlob
   import numpy as np
   import os
   import nltk
   nltk.download('stopwords')
   from nltk.corpus import stopwords
   stop = stopwords.words('english')

   path = 'Desktop/fanbase2.csv'
   df = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=',', header='infer', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
   #remove punctuation
   df['response'] = df.response.str.replace("[^\w\s]", "")
   #make it all lower case
   df['response'] = df.response.apply(lambda x: x.lower())
   #Handle strange character in source
   df['response'] = df.response.str.replace("‰Ûª", "''")

   df['response'] = df['response'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the list comprehension (last line), you are checking each word against stop word and if the word is not in the stop word, you are returning it. But you are passing a string to it. You need to split the string for the LC to work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'response':['This is one type of response!', 'Though i like this one more', 'and yet what is that?']})

df['response'] = df.response.str.replace("[^\w\s]", "").str.lower()

df['response'] = df['response'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x.split() if item not in stop])


0    [one, type, response]
1      [though, like, one]
2                    [yet]
```

If you want to return the response as string, change the last line to

```
df['response'] = df['response'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x.split() if item not in stop]))

0    one type response
1      though like one
2                  yet
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly! Sorry for the stupid question, but how does .split() know to split at the space without it being explicitly defined?

Comment: The default separator for split is space. If you string is separated by some other separator, you need to specify that but thats rarely the case with sentences :)

Comment: Thank you for all your help! :) :) :)